# Nested_Lists in python 3.0

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

explain how it works marks=[marks for name, marks in marksheet]

```
marksheet = []
for i in range(0, int(input())):
    marksheet.append([raw_input(), float(input())])
marks = [marks for name, marks in marksheet]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Answer is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) but read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first!

Comment: Why are you using Python 3.0 instead of 3.7, or at least something like 3.3? Besides being a decade out of date, 3.0 was never all that usable.

Answer (score 1):

That is similar to:

```
 mark=[]
 for name,marks in marksheet:
    mark.append(marks)
```